# How to pass image and audio from one page to another with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need that it pass image and audio of product to checkout page,I already did that with price of product name and licence I really dont know how , without hardcoding it please can you help me!

heres product page

```
      <header>
        <!--Nav-->
        <div class="nav container">
          <a href="">Deni Beatz</a>
          <!--Cart Icon-->
          <i class="bx bx-shopping-bag" id="cart-icon"></i>
          <div class="notification" id="cart-notification">0</div>
          <!--Cart-->
          <div class="cart">
            <h2 class="cart-title">Your Cart</h2>
            <!--Content-->
            <div class="cart-content">
              <div class="cart-content">
                
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--Total-->
            <div class="total">
              <div class="total-title">Total</div>
              <div class="total-price" id="total-price total">$0</div>
            </div>
            <!--Buy Button-->
            <form action="checkout.html">
            <button type="button" class="btn-buy" onclick="window.location.href = 'checkout.html';">Continue to purchase</button>
            </form>
            <!--Cart Close-->
            <i class="bx bx-x" id="close-cart"></i>
            <!-- Continue to purchase button moved here -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>

          <section id="prodetails" class="section-p1">
            <div class="productcontainer" id="enjoy">
                <div class="single-pro-image">
                  <img src="../data/high.png"  width="100%" id="product-image" class="product-img">
                </div>
            
                <div class="single-pro-details" action="C:\s\starter-ruby\client\checkout.html">
                  <h4 class="product-title" id="title">Enjoy</h4>
                  <h2 id="price" class="price">$20</h2>
                  <select id="select" class="licence">
                    <option>Select Licence</option>
                    <option>MP3</option>
                    <option>Tagged Wav</option>
                    <option>Un-Tagged Wav</option>
                    <option>Stems</option>
                    <option>Exlusive</option>
                  </select>
    
                    <script>
                      let select = document.getElementById('select');
                      let price = document.getElementById('price');
    
                      // Prices
                      let prices = {
                        "Select Licence": '$20',
                        "MP3": '$20',
                        "Tagged Wav": '$27',
                        "Un-Tagged Wav": '$30',
                        "Stems": '$120',
                        "Exlusive": '$300'
                      }
    
                      // When the value of select changes, this event listener fires and changes the text content of price to the coresponding value from the prices object
                      select.addEventListener('change', () => {
                        price.textContent = prices[select.value];
                      });
                    </script>
                    <button class="add-cart">Add To Cart <i class='bx bx-cart-add add-cart'></i></button>
                    <h4>Product Details</h4>
                    <span>Lil Tjay x Trap Type Beat - "Enjoy" in key D# Minor and 160 BPM,It has vibe of Lil Tjay , Pop Smoke and more , Prices are great for this type of beat;Tagged Mastered MP3 for $25,$27 for Tagged Unmastered Wav,$30 for Untagged unmastered Wav,$70 for Stems and $120 for Exlusive</span>
                </div>
                <div id="audio">
                    <audio controls style="width:100%;" id="audio-clip">
                        <source src="Audio/Enjoy 160 x D sharp minor.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
                    </audio>
                </div>
              </section> 

    <script>
                var selectedItems = [];
                const addToCartButton = document.querySelector('.add-cart');
                if (addToCartButton) {
                  addToCartButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    const productTitle = document.querySelector('#title').textContent;
                    const productPrice = document.querySelector('#price').textContent;
                    const selectedLicense = document.querySelector('#select').value;

                    const cartItem = {
                    title: productTitle,
                    price: productPrice,
                    license: selectedLicense,
                };
              
                    selectedItems.push(cartItem);
              
                    console.log(selectedItems);
              
                    localStorage.setItem('selectedItems', JSON.stringify(selectedItems));
                  });
                }
              </script>
```

and heres checkout page

```
  <h2 style="text-align:center;">Checkout</h2>
<div id="cart-items">
  <p style="text-align:center;">YOU ADDED THIS PRODUCTS</p>
  <hr />
  <div class="product-container">
      <div class="cart-items"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="total">
  <h3 style="text-align:center;">Tax: <br><span id="tax"></span></h3>
  <h3 style="text-align:center;">Subtotal: <br><span id="subtotal"></span></h3>
  <h3 style="text-align:center;">Total: <br><span id="total"></span></h3>
  <a href="http://localhost:4242"><button style="display:block;">Continue to payment</button></a>
  <a href="http://localhost:4242"><button style="display:block; background-color: rgb(216, 4, 4);">Cancel</button></a> <!--Make next to eachself and red and blue color for button-->
</div>

<script>
const cartItemsDiv = document.querySelector(".cart-items");
const storedCartItem = localStorage.getItem("selectedItems");
const taxRate = 0.1; // 10% tax rate
let subtotal = 0;

if (storedCartItem) {
  const cartItem = JSON.parse(storedCartItem); // Parse the storedCartItem string into an array

  for (let i = 0; i < cartItem.length; i++) {
    const cartItemElement = document.createElement("div");

    cartItemElement.innerHTML = `
    <h3>${cartItem[i].title}</h3>
    <p>Price: ${cartItem[i].price}</p>
    <p>License: ${cartItem[i].license}</p>
    `;
    cartItemsDiv.appendChild(cartItemElement);

    const price = Number(cartItem[i].price.replace("$", "")); // Parse price as a number and remove dollar sign
    subtotal += price;
  }

  const subtotalElement = document.querySelector("#subtotal");
  subtotalElement.textContent = `$${subtotal.toFixed(2)}`;

  const taxElement = document.querySelector("#tax");
  const tax = subtotal * taxRate;
  taxElement.textContent = `$${tax.toFixed(2)}`;

  const totalElement = document.querySelector("#total");
  const total = subtotal + tax;
  totalElement.textContent = `$${total.toFixed(2)}`;
}
</script>
```

It display name licence and price of added products but now i need that it display image and audio of added product without hardcoding it !

Comment: but it just does not display image and audio